# Why is my $.get() callback function never called, when sending data to the Express server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

Can someone tell me why my callback function:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/", msg, function(data) {
                        alert("Data" + data);
                    });
```

is never called?

The server gets the request and prints to the console, but my client (HTML page below) never seems to get a response.

Here is the Express server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Message! : GET");
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Message! : POST");
    res.send('Hello World');
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

And here is the HTML page making request to the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Client</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Client</h1>

        <form action="">
            <fieldset>
                Name:<br><br>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                <br><br>
                Message:<br><br>
                <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value"Submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <br><br>

        <textarea style="max-height:400px; min-height:400px; max-width:300; min-width:300px; resize: none"></textarea>

        </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var msg = {
                        Name: document.getElementById("name").value,
                        Message: document.getElementById("message").value
                    };


                    $.get("http://localhost:8080/", msg, function(data) {
                        alert("Data" + data);
                    });

        }, false);
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of the console to ensure the response to the request is `200 OK`?

Comment: Is it not called or does the call (to the server) fail.

Comment: See the Same-Origin Policy

Comment: Try to use callback for `$.get` like `$.get( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });`

Comment: I get error and finished? But the server prints "console.log("Message! : GET");" to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below to see what error message you get (Posted as response for lisibility of code)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){ 

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
          alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get no response now :S

Comment: So try `alert("toto")` in the `success function`. It should go through one of them